# Timeout Error - DHL API to Google Sheets - UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, urlfetch

In Python I use as headers the "Request Headers" that are in the request captured using the browser's developer options and it works fine.

I tried the same with Apps Script, but `UrlFetchApp` retrieves `Timeout exception`:

```
function WS() {
  var myHeaders = {
  'accept': '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
  'cookie': '', //the cookies that appear here in my browser
  'referer': 'https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=4045339815',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.53',
  'x-sec-clge-req-type': 'ajax',
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': myHeaders,
}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.dhl.com/utapi?trackingNumber=4045339815&language=en&source=tt",options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
};
```

I would appreciate any ideas / hint.

**EDIT :**

Website to catch cookies :
https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=4045339815

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is most likely the `user-agent` header. Apps Script's [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) uses Google's servers to send the request instead of your browser. As a result, Apps Script forces its own user agent that looks like this:

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: ...)"
```

On the other hand, Python sends the headers exactly as you specified them. You can test this yourself by sending your requests to a test server like https://httpbin.org/headers. The only difference between the Python and Apps Script requests is the `user-agent` header.

It doesn't look like there's a way to bypass this. There's a request in Google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758197) to allow customization of the user agent but it's been open since 2013 so it doesn't seem like something they want to do, maybe for transparency reasons or something similar.

The reason why this header would be a problem is because DHL doesn't want you to use their user-facing endpoints to request information with scripts, though you probably already know this since you're trying to replicate the browser's headers and cookies. Trying to access the endpoint without the right headers just results in this message:

[image]

My guess is that DHL has blacklisted the Apps Script user agent, hence the timeout. If you want to use Apps Script you probably will have to go to https://developer.dhl and set up a developer account to get your own API key. If you want to keep using your current method then you'll have to stick to Python or anything else that won't change your headers.

##### Edit:

Here's a quick Python sample that seems to support the theory:

```py
import requests
#Chrome user agent, this works
useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.53'

#No user agent, this also works
#useragent = ''

#Fake user agent, this still works
#useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlu-Opps-Script)'

#Apps Script user agent, this just hangs
#useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script)'

headers= {
  'accept': '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
  'cookie': 'your-cookie',
  'referer': 'https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=4045339815',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': useragent,
  'x-sec-clge-req-type': 'ajax'}

url="https://www.dhl.com/utapi?trackingNumber=4045339815&language=en&source=tt"

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(result.content.decode())
```

Based on my testing in Python, even a blank or fake user agent will work, but one that has `Google-Apps-Script` will just keep hanging. Even changing a single letter to `Google-Opps-Script` or something similar will make it work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and write an answer Daniel. You see, I tried to validate if that was actually the problem but I'm not so sure. I just learned that the reason why I needed to update the value inside the "Cookie" key in the headers it's because the Set-Cookie has an expiration time and even in Python, if the Cookie expired, the console would wait forever to receive a response just like AppScript console did

Comment: It's like if the cookie was the problem. I just wrote this "'cookie': 'sdfsdf'" and I also returns Timeout Exception instead of an authentication problem.  I thought it would be weird to receive a Timeout exception error ( the console kept waiting for 10 minutes or so for a response ) instead of a  400 error.  I looked up in https://user-agents.net the AppScript default user agent and used it in Python an it worked just fine... :(

Comment: Hello Ignacio, how did you test exactly? I tried it as well in Python with Apps Script's user agent and it also just hangs with no response. Testing with an expired or invalid cookie does not yield a timeout but instead a `403: Access denied` error, even with your sample `sdfsdf` cookie. At least in my case the only thing that triggered a timeout is the Apps Script header. I edited my answer to add the sample code I used.

Comment: Also, I didn't do deep testing with this but the cookie seems to have a `max-age` expiration of 1 year, but it also becomes invalid after using it a certain amount of times.

Comment: Hi Daniel , sorry for the delayed response. I was thinking it's a problem of me not knowing how to pass a cookie in appscript fetch headers. I used the code you wrote as "edit" but with user-agent':'asdfg' and it works just fine this is the website where you can get the cookies : https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=4045339815

Comment: Yeah, any other user agent seems to work fine, at least in my tests the only one that failed was `'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script)'`. The cookie is definitely necessary but a bad cookie does return an error while the apps script user agent is the one that just hangs indefinitely.