# How can I import data from a website with a POST API request into google sheets, using information from the sheet to populate the request?

Tags: xml, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I am trying to build a spreadsheet to retrieve the prices of different chemical compounds on different websites. The user would enter a CAS number (standardised unique identifier for chemicals) and the sheet would retrieve the first three prices listed on the product page of different websites. For some websites this is easy, just using IMPORTXML. However, sigmaaldrich.com is displayed entirely with javascript, so IMPORTXML finds nothing to extract. I've been lead to believe that I need to use a POST API request, and by using chrome devtools and refresh the network tab, I've found the relevant Header, Payload, and Response data. I found a custom script called IMPORTJSONAPI that looks like it might do what I'm trying to do, but I've struggled to implement it so far.

This is the API: [www.sigmaaldrich.com/api](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/api)

This is the request payload:

```
{'operationName':'PricingAndAvailability','variables':{'displaySDS':false,'productNumber':'518751','materialIds':['518751-1G','518751-5G'],'brand':'ALDRICH','quantity':1,'catalogType':'sial','orgId':null,'checkForPb':true,'dealerId':''},'query':'query PricingAndAvailability($productNumber: String!, $brand: String, $quantity: Int!, $catalogType: CatalogType, $checkForPb: Boolean, $orgId: String, $materialIds: [String!], $displaySDS: Boolean = false, $dealerId: String) {  getPricingForProduct(input: {productNumber: $productNumber, brand: $brand, quantity: $quantity, catalogType: $catalogType, checkForPb: $checkForPb, orgId: $orgId, materialIds: $materialIds, dealerId: $dealerId}) {    ...ProductPricingDetail    __typename  }
}

fragment ProductPricingDetail on ProductPricing {
  dealerId
  productNumber
  country
  materialPricing {
    ...ValidMaterialPricingDetail
    __typename
  }
  discontinuedPricingInfo {
    ...DiscontinuedMaterialPricingDetail
    __typename
  }
  dchainMessage
  productInfo {
    ...ProductInfoMessageDetail    __typename  }  __typename}

fragment ValidMaterialPricingDetail on ValidMaterialPricing {
  brand
  type
  currency
  dealerId
  listPriceCurrency
  listPrice
  shipsToday
  freeFreight
  sdsLanguages
  catalogType
  marketplaceOfferId
  marketplaceSellerId
  materialDescription
  materialNumber
  netPrice
  packageSize
  price
  product
  productGroupSBU
  quantity
  isPBAvailable
  vendorSKU
  availabilities {
    ...Availabilities
    __typename
  }
  additionalInfo {
    ...AdditionalInfo
    __typename
  }
  promotionalMessage {
    ...PromotionalMessage
    __typename
  }
  ... @include(if: $displaySDS) {
    sdsLanguages
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

fragment Availabilities on MaterialAvailability {
  date
  key
  plantLoc
  quantity
  displayFromLink
  displayInquireLink
  messageType
  contactInfo {
    contactPhone
    contactEmail
    __typename
  }
  availabilityOverwriteMessage {
    messageKey
    messageValue
    messageVariable1
    messageVariable2
    messageVariable3
    __typename
  }
  supplementaryMessage {
    messageKey
    messageValue
    messageVariable1
    messageVariable2
    messageVariable3
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

fragment AdditionalInfo on CartAdditionalInfo {
  carrierRestriction
  unNumber
  tariff
  casNumber
  jfcCode
  pdcCode
  __typename
}

fragment PromotionalMessage on PromotionalMessage {
  messageKey
  messageValue
  messageVariable1
  messageVariable2
  messageVariable3
  __typename
}

fragment DiscontinuedMaterialPricingDetail on DiscontinuedMaterialPricing {
  errorMsg
  paramList
  hideReplacementProductLink
  displaySimilarProductLabel
  hideTechnicalServiceLink
  replacementProducts {
    ...ReplacementProductDetail
    __typename
  }
  alternateMaterials {
    ...AlternateMaterialDetail
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

fragment ReplacementProductDetail on Product {
  productNumber
  name
  description
  sdsLanguages
  images {
    mediumUrl
    altText
    __typename
  }
  brand {
    key
    erpKey
    name
    logo {
      smallUrl
      altText
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

fragment AlternateMaterialDetail on Material {
  number
  __typename
}

fragment ProductInfoMessageDetail on ProductInfoMessage {
  productNumber
  messageType
  message
  __typename
}
'}
```

And here is the response (I added line breaks to break it up a bit, the actual response is all on one line):

```
{"data":{"getPricingForProduct":{"dealerId":null,"productNumber":"518751","country":"US","materialPricing":[{"brand":"ALDRICH","type":"Prepack","currency":"USD","dealerId":null,"listPriceCurrency":"USD",
"listPrice":47.7,"shipsToday":true,"freeFreight":false,"sdsLanguages":[],"catalogType":"sial","marketplaceOfferId":null,"marketplaceSellerId":null,"materialDescription":"4-AMINOPHENYLBORONIC ACID PINACOL ESTER,",
"materialNumber":"518751-1G","netPrice":47.7,"packageSize":"1 G","price":47.7,"product":"518751","productGroupSBU":"774","quantity":1,"isPBAvailable":false,"vendorSKU":null,"availabilities":[{"date":1665100800000,
"key":"AVAILABLE_TO_SHIP_ON","plantLoc":"MILWAUKEE","quantity":1,"displayFromLink":true,"displayInquireLink":false,"messageType":"secondary","contactInfo":{"contactPhone":null,"contactEmail":null,
"__typename":"MaterialContactInfo"},"availabilityOverwriteMessage":null,"supplementaryMessage":null,"__typename":"MaterialAvailability"},{"date":1665100800000,"key":"AVAILABLE_TO_SHIP_ON","plantLoc":null,
"quantity":1,"displayFromLink":true,"displayInquireLink":false,"messageType":"primary","contactInfo":{"contactPhone":null,"contactEmail":null,"__typename":"MaterialContactInfo"},"availabilityOverwriteMessage":null,
"supplementaryMessage":null,"__typename":"MaterialAvailability"}],"additionalInfo":{"carrierRestriction":"","unNumber":"","tariff":"2931.90.6000","casNumber":"214360-73-3","jfcCode":"","pdcCode":"",
"__typename":"CartAdditionalInfo"},"promotionalMessage":null,"__typename":"ValidMaterialPricing"},{"brand":"ALDRICH","type":"Prepack","currency":"USD","dealerId":null,"listPriceCurrency":"USD","listPrice":213,
"shipsToday":true,"freeFreight":false,"sdsLanguages":[],"catalogType":"sial","marketplaceOfferId":null,"marketplaceSellerId":null,"materialDescription":"4-AMINOPHENYLBORONIC ACID PINACOL ESTER,",
"materialNumber":"518751-5G","netPrice":213,"packageSize":"5 G","price":213,"product":"518751","productGroupSBU":"774","quantity":1,"isPBAvailable":false,"vendorSKU":null,"availabilities":[{"date":1665100800000,
"key":"AVAILABLE_TO_SHIP_ON","plantLoc":"MILWAUKEE","quantity":1,"displayFromLink":true,"displayInquireLink":false,"messageType":"secondary","contactInfo":{"contactPhone":null,"contactEmail":null,
"__typename":"MaterialContactInfo"},"availabilityOverwriteMessage":null,"supplementaryMessage":null,"__typename":"MaterialAvailability"},{"date":1665100800000,"key":"AVAILABLE_TO_SHIP_ON","plantLoc":null,
"quantity":1,"displayFromLink":true,"displayInquireLink":false,"messageType":"primary","contactInfo":{"contactPhone":null,"contactEmail":null,"__typename":"MaterialContactInfo"},"availabilityOverwriteMessage":null,
"supplementaryMessage":null,"__typename":"MaterialAvailability"}],"additionalInfo":{"carrierRestriction":"","unNumber":"","tariff":"2931.90.6000","casNumber":"214360-73-3","jfcCode":"","pdcCode":"",
"__typename":"CartAdditionalInfo"},"promotionalMessage":null,"__typename":"ValidMaterialPricing"}],"discontinuedPricingInfo":null,"dchainMessage":null,"productInfo":null,"__typename":"ProductPricing"}}}
```

I don't know where to go from here, I've tried copying the full payload into the payload parameter of the IMPORTJSONAPI function, but it just returns Invalid JSON. Also I have no idea how I'd go about using information from a cell to populate to API request.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: Frontend]

[image: Network tab on product page]

Comment: Can you confirm the actual url of the page where you would enter a CAS, and search for it? Also a list of CASes, like 5.. how many are you after?

Comment: What does the IMPORTJSONAPI script look like?

Comment: While referring code that isn't hosted in well known libraries / packages hosting services like npm, please include a brief description about how to get that code and whenever be possible include a [mcve]. In this case, you should show how you are using the Google Apps Script Url Fetch Service. If you don't have idea of what is the Url Fetch Service, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch

Comment: By the way, not all sites could be scraped using Google Apps Script. You could use a library like cheerio.js to help you to parse html but it will not replicate how the website works, i.e. the site might dynamically generate a session token or require data from a cookie.

Comment: You can search on any page, but this is the dedicated search page: 
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/search
Searching by CAS requires you to select it from the dropdown normally. 
Here are 5 example CAS numbers:
```16629-19-9 

37566-39-5 

4214-57-7 

15864-32-1 

823-54-1```
The IMPORTJSONAPI code can be found here:
https://github.com/qeet/IMPORTJSONAPI

Comment: About `This is the API: www.sigmaaldrich.com/api`, can you provide the official document for checking the specification of the API? And, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Unfortunately the API has no public documentation I can find, I expect to be able to input a product code and receive the pricing information for the different quantities available

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** You cannot do it with just Google Sheets/Apps Script due to restrictions in sigmaaldrich.com.

**Explanation:**

After much trial and error I was able to figure out how the API works and there are a few requirements you need to meet before sending the request. Unfortunately, due to (probably) some anti-scraping measures you won't be able to just use Sheets to do this.

First, here's what you need to get the data from the `https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/api` endpoint. Failing to add any of these resulted in the server never responding to the request or some sort of error message:

- HTTP headers `accept-encoding`, `content-type`, `user-agent`, `x-gql-access-token`, `x-gql-country` and `x-gql-operation-name`.
- A payload with the pre-built query. They use the same API endpoint but with different [GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) queries to get the data. It seems that you can just take the query from the developer tools and keep reusing it while just changing the product code. The `PricingAndAvailability` payload that you got is the correct one.

The IMPORTJSONAPI script that you found has the necessary tools to do this. The problem is that the server stops responding until it times out. After further testing I concluded that the cause is the same issue I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887372/12306687). To sum it up, the `user-agent` header when using `UrlFetchApp` in Apps Script cannot be changed, and some servers reject its user agent, probably to prevent scraping. I tested it in Python with the same results as the answer I linked: When setting the user agent to `Google-Apps-Script` the server times out, but setting it to anything else still works. This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758197).

Since Apps Script is out of the picture I tried it out with this Python script:

```py
import requests
import json

productnumber = "708291"

payload = {
   "operationName":"PricingAndAvailability",
   "variables":{
      "displaySDS":False,
      "productNumber":productnumber,
      "materialIds":[
         f"{productnumber}-1G",
         f"{productnumber}-5G",
         f"{productnumber}-25G"
      ],
      "brand":"ALDRICH",
      "quantity":1,
      "catalogType":"sial",
      "orgId":"None",
      "checkForPb":True,
      "dealerId":""
   },
   "query":"query PricingAndAvailability($productNumber: String!, $brand: String, $quantity: Int!, $catalogType: CatalogType, $checkForPb: Boolean, $orgId: String, $materialIds: [String!], $displaySDS: Boolean = false, $dealerId: String) {\n  getPricingForProduct(input: {productNumber: $productNumber, brand: $brand, quantity: $quantity, catalogType: $catalogType, checkForPb: $checkForPb, orgId: $orgId, materialIds: $materialIds, dealerId: $dealerId}) {\n    ...ProductPricingDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProductPricingDetail on ProductPricing {\n  dealerId\n  productNumber\n  country\n  materialPricing {\n    ...ValidMaterialPricingDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n  discontinuedPricingInfo {\n    ...DiscontinuedMaterialPricingDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n  dchainMessage\n  productInfo {\n    ...ProductInfoMessageDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ValidMaterialPricingDetail on ValidMaterialPricing {\n  brand\n  type\n  currency\n  dealerId\n  listPriceCurrency\n  listPrice\n  shipsToday\n  freeFreight\n  sdsLanguages\n  catalogType\n  marketplaceOfferId\n  marketplaceSellerId\n  materialDescription\n  materialNumber\n  netPrice\n  packageSize\n  price\n  product\n  productGroupSBU\n  quantity\n  isPBAvailable\n  vendorSKU\n  availabilities {\n    ...Availabilities\n    __typename\n  }\n  additionalInfo {\n    ...AdditionalInfo\n    __typename\n  }\n  promotionalMessage {\n    ...PromotionalMessage\n    __typename\n  }\n  ... @include(if: $displaySDS) {\n    sdsLanguages\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment Availabilities on MaterialAvailability {\n  date\n  key\n  plantLoc\n  quantity\n  displayFromLink\n  displayInquireLink\n  messageType\n  contactInfo {\n    contactPhone\n    contactEmail\n    __typename\n  }\n  availabilityOverwriteMessage {\n    messageKey\n    messageValue\n    messageVariable1\n    messageVariable2\n    messageVariable3\n    __typename\n  }\n  supplementaryMessage {\n    messageKey\n    messageValue\n    messageVariable1\n    messageVariable2\n    messageVariable3\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AdditionalInfo on CartAdditionalInfo {\n  carrierRestriction\n  unNumber\n  tariff\n  casNumber\n  jfcCode\n  pdcCode\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PromotionalMessage on PromotionalMessage {\n  messageKey\n  messageValue\n  messageVariable1\n  messageVariable2\n  messageVariable3\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment DiscontinuedMaterialPricingDetail on DiscontinuedMaterialPricing {\n  errorMsg\n  paramList\n  hideReplacementProductLink\n  displaySimilarProductLabel\n  hideTechnicalServiceLink\n  replacementProducts {\n    ...ReplacementProductDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n  alternateMaterials {\n    ...AlternateMaterialDetail\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReplacementProductDetail on Product {\n  productNumber\n  name\n  description\n  sdsLanguages\n  images {\n    mediumUrl\n    altText\n    __typename\n  }\n  brand {\n    key\n    erpKey\n    name\n    logo {\n      smallUrl\n      altText\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AlternateMaterialDetail on Material {\n  number\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductInfoMessageDetail on ProductInfoMessage {\n  productNumber\n  messageType\n  message\n  __typename\n}\n"
}

headers = {"accept-encoding": "application/json",
"content-type": "application/json",
"user-agent": "",
"x-gql-access-token": "",
"x-gql-country": "US",
"x-gql-operation-name": "PricingAndAvailability"
}

req = requests.post("https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/api",data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(req.text)
```

Which does return the response you'd expect:

```js
{
   "data":{
      "getPricingForProduct":{
         "dealerId":null,
         "productNumber":"708291",
         "country":"US",
         "materialPricing":[
            {
               "brand":"ALDRICH",
               "type":"Prepack",
               "currency":"USD",
               "dealerId":null,
               "listPriceCurrency":"USD",
               "listPrice":33.4,
               "shipsToday":false,
               "freeFreight":false,
               "sdsLanguages":[
                  
               ],
               "catalogType":"sial",
               "marketplaceOfferId":null,
               "marketplaceSellerId":null,
               "materialDescription":"2-AMINO-5-BROMO-1,3,4-THIADIAZOLE, 95% &",
               "materialNumber":"708291-1G",
               "netPrice":33.4,
               "packageSize":"1 G",
               "price":33.4,
               "product":"708291",
               "productGroupSBU":"774",
               "quantity":1,
               "isPBAvailable":false,
               "vendorSKU":null,
               "availabilities":[
                  {
                     "date":1665446400000,
                     "key":"AVAILABLE_TO_SHIP_ON",
                     "plantLoc":"MILWAUKEE",
                     "quantity":1,
                     "displayFromLink":true,
                     "displayInquireLink":false,
                     "messageType":"secondary",
                     "contactInfo":{
                        "contactPhone":null,
                        "contactEmail":null,
                        "__typename":"MaterialContactInfo"
                     },
                     "availabilityOverwriteMessage":null,
                     "supplementaryMessage":null,
                     "__typename":"MaterialAvailability"
                  },
                  {
                     "date":0,
                     "key":"ONLY_FEW_LEFT_IN_STOCK",
                     "plantLoc":null,
                     "quantity":1,
                     "displayFromLink":true,
                     "displayInquireLink":false,
                     "messageType":"primary",
                     "contactInfo":{
                        "contactPhone":null,
                        "contactEmail":null,
                        "__typename":"MaterialContactInfo"
                     },
                     "availabilityOverwriteMessage":null,
                     "supplementaryMessage":null,
                     "__typename":"MaterialAvailability"
                  }
               ],
               "additionalInfo":{
                  "carrierRestriction":"",
                  "unNumber":"",
                  "tariff":"2934.99.9001",
                  "casNumber":"37566-39-5",
                  "jfcCode":"",
                  "pdcCode":"",
                  "__typename":"CartAdditionalInfo"
               },
               "promotionalMessage":null,
               "__typename":"ValidMaterialPricing"
            }
         ],
         "discontinuedPricingInfo":null,
         "dchainMessage":"PRODUCT_DISCONTINUED_BUT_AVAILABLE_FOR_PURCHASE",
         "productInfo":null,
         "__typename":"ProductPricing"
      }
   }
}
```

A few things to note:

- You can have whatever `user-agent` header as long as it doesn't have `Google-Apps` in it. Leaving it blank is good enough.
- The `x-gql-access-token` header suggests that you need an access token, which does get sent if you check the developer tools in the browser. You can also find it stored in a variable called `accessToken` if you check the source code of any page where you can make a search. Normally this would mean that you first have to fetch this token from the search page, and then include it in the headers, but in practice I was able to leave the field blank and the query went through as long as the header was set. I don't know if the authentication is just not working properly or if there are some server-side caching shenanigans that allowed me to send blank tokens, but it's something to keep in mind in case that other pages do require it.
- The script assumes that you already know the product number, brand and probably some other fields in the payload. For the script to really work by searching CAS numbers or just a product name you first would need to send another query that has the `"operationName":"ProductSearch"` payload, then use the resulting JSON to fill out the `PricingAndAvailability` query.

There's still the issue of actually getting this data to your spreadsheet. You could probably use the Python script to connect to the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) to fill it out, or you could even turn the script into an API endpoint that won't reject the IMPORTJSONAPI function and have it work as some sort of middleman.

All in all, there's a fair bit or work needed, more than can be included in just this answer, but I hope this gives you an idea of how it all works.